# Removing DLLs from the x64 folder does not cause application to fail

Tags: .net, visual-c++, dll, emgucv

I have an EMGU CV application written in C# that installs the following DLLs in the bin\Debug\x64 folder:

*cvextern.dll

concrt140.dll

msvcp140.dll

msvcp140_1.dll

msvcp140_2.dll

msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll

opencv_videoio_ffmpeg440_64.dll

vcruntime140.dll

vcruntime140_1.dll*

I tried deleting the DLLs except cvextern.dll, and the application (with a hello-world type simple functionality) still ran fine.

Is this because the DLLs are also located elsewhere on my system, in standard places that the runtime looks at?  Or is it because the simple application I have does not make any calls into the DLLs I have deleted?

I know that the *cvextern.dll* is not managed code, which is why I assume the C/C++ runtime DLLs are deployed.  Is my assumption correct?

Also, what are the *_1* and *_2* versions of the DLLs for?

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you.  The Modules window is a good idea, but it's interesting that even if I remove the DLLs manually, Visual Studio re-populates the x64 folder when I start a debug session.  I didn't know this.  I was under the impression that bin\Debug folder population happened once per build.

Comment: @HansPassant You are helpful, but you do not follow up. :(